# iTextPDF: Setting Artbox & Trimbox for PDF

Tags: itext, pdf-generation

I am setting PDF/X conformance using iText.

Having trimbox and artbox is one of the requirement of PDF/X. How can it be set? Im using the following code to set page size,
pageSize = new com.lowagie.text.Rectangle(height, width); 
document = new Document(pageSize, 0, 0, 0, 0);

Kindly Help.

Comment: Don't use versions of iText with my name in the package names. When I see my name in your code, I know that you are using a version of iText that is obsolete and therefore unsupported. The last version with my name in the packages dates from July 2009. Those versions also can't be used in a commercial context. See [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page boundaries can be set using the `setBoxSize()` method. For instance:

```
writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 36, 559, 806));
writer.setBoxSize("trim", new Rectangle(36, 36, 559, 806));
```

I don't know when the `setBoxSize()` method was introduced, but I see my name in your code sample. When I see my name in your code, I know that you are using a version of iText that is obsolete and therefore unsupported. The last version with my name in the packages dates from July 2009. Please understand that those versions also can't be used in a commercial context because of IP issues that were discovered *after* those versions were released under the LGPL.

See [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/faq/can-itext-2-1-7-itextsharp-4-1-6-or-earlier-be-used-commercially) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We are using iText2.1.2 and iText5.4 in different releases.  Your code is working in 2.1.2 also.   Yes, we are considering upgrading to latest version 
sometime soon.